# Evaluating couple PDE with Homotopy Analysis Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, homotopy-theory, nonlinear-system, maple

Can some one provide me a simple code for Homotopy Analysis Method in Maple?
I have coupled nonlinear PDEs and have calculated the first order answers on paper.
I need the mth order answer and I don't know how to write a code in Maple to evaluate it.
Kindly guide me, as I can solve my problem.
Or could anyone please give me any reference about it?
Thanks.

P.s:
Here are my equations:
https://ibb.co/daJDQF